# Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference -> resolve?

Tags: kotlin

I try to do a button for switch from a main activity to an other, but when I try to run the app, it close itself immediatly after click on the app. I find in the command that message of error :
`Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{fr.amseu.mystretching/fr.amseu.mystretching.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference` 
My code in the MainActivity is this one :

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val button = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.imageButton)

        button.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent);}
```

That is my Main Activity :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/item_main"
    android:background="@color/light_red">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/lower_legs"
            android:contentDescription="@string/home_page_first_button" />

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_separation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name_item"
        style="@style/SubTitleTextStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/default_margin"
        android:text="@string/home_page_first_button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view_separation"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/cardView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description_item"
        style="@style/DefaultTextStyle"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/home_page_description_1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/name_item"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view_separation" />



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And for my recycler view, I take this model in my page and the following item are siblings but I change the image and texts, with an adapter, HomeFragment...
Can someone help me please ?
(It is my first app)
Thanks a lot !

Comment: A button with this ID doesn’t exist in your layout. Consider using view binding to avoid this kind of problem.

Comment: I am not sure to understand @Tenfour04, my ImageButton already exist in my main layout and it's id is : imageButton ? I would to redirect the person after the click on the SecondActivity.

Comment: Double-check it closely. You could post your layout code here too for us to take a look. But the missing ID or forgetting to call `setContentView` are the only reasons I've ever seen for `findViewById` to return null.

Comment: For sure, I use it with a recycler view, I don't know if it doesn't match ? It is in a Card View like this :
`<ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/lower_legs"
            android:contentDescription="@string/home_page_first_button" />`
If you know too how can I with my Recycler View redirect the user to different pages following the image pressed ? :)

Comment: What do you mean you use it with a RecyclerView? Can you edit your question to add the entire content of `activity_main.xml`?

Comment: it is done if you would take a look ;) @Tenfour04

Comment: I can't find any problems with what you've shown. Only thing I can think of for you to check is to be absolutely sure this file is `activity_main.xml` and it is in `res/layout`, and not some specific layout directory such as `layout-land`.

Comment: Is the layout you posted the content of activity_main.xml like I asked for, or some item view for use in your RecyclerView? If it’s an item in your RecyclerView, then it doesn’t exist yet when you’re trying to get its button. You can only work with RecyclerView items from within the Adapter of the RecyclerView.